# Error in selecting menu

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is class written for a homepage of http://www.royalmailgroup.com/
I am trying to click on About us link and FOI contacts.

```
package sample.keyword;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.Coordinates;
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.internal.EventFiringMouse;


 public class FeeToPay {

    public static WebElement Menu, SubMenu ;
    public static InternetExplorerDriver driver;
    //public static FirefoxDriver driver;
    public static EventFiringWebDriver eDriver;
    public static EventFiringMouse eMouse;
    public static String xpathMainMenu ="//div[@class='content']/ul/li/span/*";


public void OpenApplication(String Url) throws Exception{

            File file = new File("D:\\Software\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();

            //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            eDriver= new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
            eMouse= new EventFiringMouse(eDriver, null);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        try{
            String baseUrl = "http://www.royalmailgroup.com/";
            this.driver.get(baseUrl);

        }
        catch(Exception E){
                throw E;
        }
    }
    public static EventFiringWebDriver getWebDriver(){
        return eDriver;
    }
    public void NavigateTo(String strMenuPath) throws Exception {
    if(strMenuPath == null || strMenuPath.isEmpty())throw new Exception("no menu path mentioned");

    String [] MenuItems = strMenuPath.split("->");
    java.util.List<WebElement> liMenuItems;
    liMenuItems= FeeToPay.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath(xpathMainMenu));


    for (int counter =0; counter<MenuItems.length;counter++ ){

        if(counter==0){
            if(liMenuItems.get(counter).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(MenuItems[counter])){
                Locatable item = (Locatable)liMenuItems.get(counter);
                Coordinates c =  item.getCoordinates();
                eMouse.mouseMove(c);
                                }

       }
        if(counter!=0 && counter == MenuItems.length-1 ){
            eDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                WebElement ele = eDriver.findElement(By.linkText(MenuItems[counter]));
                ele.click();
        }
     }
```

}
}

I am getting below error
[VerboseTestNG] FAILED: "sample.keyword.FeeToPayTest" - sample.keyword.FeeToPayTest.testOpenApplication() finished in 9033 ms
[VerboseTestNG] org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: The point at which the driver is attempting to click on the element was not scrolled into the viewport. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
[VerboseTestNG] Command duration or timeout: 1.93 seconds

I am using 
Selenium Jar Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', 
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'

Comment: Are you waiting till that component gets fully loaded to webpage?

Comment: the first  if loop in  for loop is to hover on first menu item ' Aboout us'.the second if loop is to click submenuitem. I am not waiting in between this.

Comment: I just payed with selenium in my free time. It looks like you you are not autogenerating you test case through selenium and then converting to TestNG java code. However you can use Explicit and implicit wait. Follow this link  [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

need to add 
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(eDriver,10);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(MenuItems[counter])));
before clicking on submenuitem.

Comment: +1 Now as you got the answer. Accept it and close the question.